# Can i use .net Authentication call in Openedge/ABL code?

Tags: .net, openedge

I was curious if it possible to use .net Active Directory calls in Progress/Openedge?

is it as simple as using a using statement like so? It is it more complicated or not at all possible?

```
USING System.Net.NetworkInformation.*.

// do whatever work here to check against it.
```

Perhaps something like this?

```
define variable test as char no-undo.
test = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.DomainName.
```

I am currently scouring the internet but if you know of any resources or examples that would be great. Thank you much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The availability of .NET in OpenEdge depends greatly on your OpenEdge version.

Prior to 10.2A the answer is mostly "no".

Releases after 10.2A have increasingly more support for .NET.

Of course the specifics of what you are trying to do are also kind of important.  But being able to generally call .NET is certainly possible in any modern release of OpenEgde.

Lots of people successfully tie OpenEdge into Active Directory.  There are some pretty good Progress kbase articles on the topic:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/pkb_Home?q=active%20directory&l=en_US&c=Product_Group%3AOpenEdge

Comment: Thank you. This is a huge help. I was able to find away use the .net. It was easier then I thought it was going to be. I'll post a small and simple part of what I did in case anyone else needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
USING System.Net.NetworkInformation.* FROM ASSEMBLY.
DEFINE VARIABLE someObj AS CLASS IPGlobalProperties NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE someDomaninName AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
someDomaninName = IPGlobalProperties:GetIPGlobalProperties():DomainName.
```